# Nested AD group is not able to get permissions on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, active-directory, groups

I have this case:
**DOMAIN1\GroupA** (Group type "Security", scope "Domain Local") 
**DOMAIN2\GroupB** (Group type "Security", scope "Global") 
GroupB is inside GroupA.
In a SharePoint subsite I have a SharePoint group which contains GroupA. 
Users inside GroupB are not able to get permissions on this site. I can't test directly if users inside GroupA are able because this group is just a "container".
Is there a particular reason why this is not working? Maybe is because GroupA and GroupB are from different domains? Or maybe because the Global group is inside the Domain Local one?
I can provide to you more informations if it's required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested AD Groups are not recommended with SharePoint and can lead to the results you're seeing. Unnest the groups [with SharePoint].

Comment: Can you provide some articles that explain this case? It will be helpful a lot to me.

Comment: First, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261972.aspx. Second issue is that if you're crossing forests domain boundaries, SharePoint will see objects within the group on the external domain as a Foreign Security Principal. SharePoint cannot 'see' FSPs. You can add users to a group in DOMAIN2 and assign that group to SharePoint, but users who are enumerated through a group in DOMAIN1 but exist in DOMAIN2 won't work due to them being an FSP to DOMAIN1.